# Error: TodoList has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: deployment, blockchain, truffle

truffle(development)> TodoList = await TodoList.deployed()
Uncaught:
Error: TodoList has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:113:1

Answer (score 0):

```
Please follow the steps:
```

1. Create another file named **2_anyname.js**(make sure it doesn't
   start with 1 and you can name it anything) in migration folder.
2. Paste this content in file

   ```
   var contract_name = artifacts.require('contract_name');

   module.exports = function (deployer) {  
   deployer.deploy(contract_name); };
   ```
3. run commands in this order : truffle compile ->
   truffle migrate --reset or truffle deploy --reset -> truffle console
4. you are good to go !!